# extracting data with regex

Tags: java, regex

well i got a nice solution here but the regex split the string into "" string and 2 other splits i needed.

```
String  Result = "<ahref=https://blabla.com/Securities_regulation_in_the_United_States>Securities regulation in the United States</a> - Securities regulation in the United States is the field of U.S. law that covers transactions and other dealings with securities.";

String [] Arr =  Result.split("<[^>]*>");
for (String elem : Arr) {
    System.out.printf(elem);
}
```

the result is:

```
Arr[0]= ""
Arr[1]= Securities regulation in the United States
Arr[2]= Securities regulation in the United States is the field of U.S. law that covers transactions and other dealings with securities.
```

the `Arr[1]` and `Arr[2]` splits are fine I just cant get rid of the `Arr[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an opposite regex to capture what you want by using a regex like this:

```
(?s)(?:^|>)(.*?)(?:<|$)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/dT2yA0/1)**

**[IDEOne Code working](https://ideone.com/7xi2bq)**

Code:

```
String line = "ahref=https://blabla.com/Securities_regulation_in_the_United_States>Securities regulation in the United States</a> - Securities regulation in the United States is the field of U.S. law that covers transactions and other dealings with securities.";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)(?:^|>)(.*?)(?:<|$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("group 1: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: did it before it didnt  work, i did it again. getting the  same result

Comment: @MattClark yes, you were right. Changed the script to match the strings instead of splitting it

Comment: for some reason still doesnt work : Arr[0]= "<a href=http//....united_states" and Arr[1]= "/a"  ... very weird

Comment: @gb051 what about this regex: `(?s)>(.*?)(?:<|$)`  ?

Comment: Try parsing `foo<div>bar</div>baz`. With your current solution `foo` will be ignored.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks! Fortunately a constructive comment. Fixed now.

Comment: If line is `"x<a><b>y"` you'd still get a blank value: `"x", "", "y"`. Prevent that by changing the capturing group part to `(.+?)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid that empty string if you are using only `split`, especially since your regex is not zero-length.

You could try removing that first match placed at start of your input, and then split in rest of matches like

```
String[] Arr =  Result.replaceFirst("^<[^>]+>","").split("<[^>]+>")
```

But generally **you should [avoid using regex with HTML\XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)**. [Try using parser instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1393766) like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: how i can remove the "-" in the 2nd sentence?

Comment: You could parse results and remove each `-` at start... You could also add this `-` to your delimiter on which you split, like `split("<[^>]+>(\\s*-\\s*)?")`.